# hiding .meta and .cs.meta files on mac in visual studio code

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-code

How do I hide those files in explorer? I tried using this code in settings.json :

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
"files.exclude": {
"\*.meta": true,
"**/*.cs.meta": true,
"**/.cs.meta": true,
"**/.cs": true
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should work:

```
"files.exclude": {
  "**/*.meta": true
}
```

If that doesn't work then:

- Ensure that you're on the latest version of VSCode.
- Or file a bug [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List).

Comment: That's great. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: @Wosi Change from back-slash to forward-slash as that would be the correct setting

Answer (score 1):

I realize the OP was looking at `.cs` files, but I don't see an answer for these elsewhere on StackOverflow, and believe this will be useful for people.  Specifically for Salesforce Apex projects, the filter you want is this:

```
"files.exclude": {
  "**/*.*meta.xml": true
}
```